# Parse JSON in Java 3 levels deep

Tags: java, json

Thank you in advanced

I'm trying to parse a JSON array from a Weather Underground api. The return I'm getting for the 10 day forecast is as follows:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version": "0.1",
  "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast10day": 1
  }
  },
  "forecast": {
  "txt_forecast": {
  "date": "8:00 AM PDT",
  "forecastday": [{
  "period": 0,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday",
  "fcttext": "Overcast in the morning, then clear. High of 75F. Winds from the SSW at 5 to 20 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Overcast in the morning, then clear. High of 24C. Windy. Winds from the SSW at 5 to 30 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 1,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Low of 55F. Winds from the SW at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Low of 13C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 2,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 72F. Winds from the SW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 15 to 25 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 3,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the SW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 15 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 4,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Thursday",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Fog early. High of 70F. Winds from the WSW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Fog early. High of 21C. Windy. Winds from the WSW at 15 to 25 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 5,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the WNW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 6,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Friday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 72F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 7,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Friday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the WNW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 8,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Saturday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog early. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog early. High of 23C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 9,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Saturday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 10,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Sunday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. High of 72F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 11,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Sunday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 12,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Monday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 70F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 21C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 13,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Monday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 14,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 75F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 24C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 15,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 59F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 15C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 16,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 23C. Winds from the West at 5 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 17,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 59F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 15C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 18,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 23C. Winds from the West at 5 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 19,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 57F. Winds from the WSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 14C. Winds from the WSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }]
  },
  "simpleforecast": {
  "forecastday": [{
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341381600",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 03, 2012",
  "day": 3,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 184,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Tue",
  "weekday": "Tuesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 1,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "75",
  "celsius": "24"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 17,
  "kph": 27,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 255
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 14,
  "kph": 22,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 241
  },
  "avehumidity": 72,
  "maxhumidity": 82,
  "minhumidity": 62
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341468000",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 04, 2012",
  "day": 4,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 185,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Wed",
  "weekday": "Wednesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 2,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "partlycloudy",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 15,
  "kph": 24,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 237
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 12,
  "kph": 19,
  "dir": "SW",
  "degrees": 231
  },
  "avehumidity": 79,
  "maxhumidity": 89,
  "minhumidity": 54
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341554400",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 05, 2012",
  "day": 5,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 186,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Thu",
  "weekday": "Thursday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 3,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "70",
  "celsius": "21"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 15,
  "kph": 24,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 265
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 13,
  "kph": 21,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 250
  },
  "avehumidity": 77,
  "maxhumidity": 87,
  "minhumidity": 64
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341640800",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 06, 2012",
  "day": 6,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 187,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Fri",
  "weekday": "Friday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 4,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 272
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 274
  },
  "avehumidity": 70,
  "maxhumidity": 84,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341727200",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 07, 2012",
  "day": 7,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 188,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Sat",
  "weekday": "Saturday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 5,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Fog",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 266
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 270
  },
  "avehumidity": 75,
  "maxhumidity": 85,
  "minhumidity": 61
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341813600",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 08, 2012",
  "day": 8,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 189,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Sun",
  "weekday": "Sunday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 6,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Fog",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "partlycloudy",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 265
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 266
  },
  "avehumidity": 79,
  "maxhumidity": 88,
  "minhumidity": 66
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341900000",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 09, 2012",
  "day": 9,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 190,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Mon",
  "weekday": "Monday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 7,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "70",
  "celsius": "21"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 10,
  "kph": 16,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 269
  },
  "avehumidity": 85,
  "maxhumidity": 92,
  "minhumidity": 67
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341986400",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 10, 2012",
  "day": 10,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 191,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Tue",
  "weekday": "Tuesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 8,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "75",
  "celsius": "24"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "59",
  "celsius": "15"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 10,
  "kph": 16,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 264
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avehumidity": 78,
  "maxhumidity": 90,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1342072800",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 11, 2012",
  "day": 11,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 192,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Wed",
  "weekday": "Wednesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 9,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "59",
  "celsius": "15"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 273
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 268
  },
  "avehumidity": 76,
  "maxhumidity": 93,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1342159200",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 12, 2012",
  "day": 12,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 193,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Thu",
  "weekday": "Thursday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 10,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "57",
  "celsius": "14"
  },
  "conditions": "Clear",
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 268
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avehumidity": 71,
  "maxhumidity": 89,
  "minhumidity": 53
  }]
  }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to drill down into: forecast > txt_forecast > {icon, icon_url, title, fcttext}.

I'm currently using a dedicated JSONParser class that isn't quite working.  It currently looks like this:

```
package com.garciaericn.forecaster.data;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Full Sail University
 * Mobile Development BS
 * Created by ENG618-Mac on 9/7/14.
 */
public class JSONParser {

    public static final String TAG = "JSONParser.TAG";


    public static List<Weather> parseForecast(String jsonString) {
        Log.i(TAG, "parseForecast entered");

        List<Weather> weatherJSON = new ArrayList<Weather>();

        try {
            // Create JSON
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            // Create Array of weather objects
            JSONArray forecast = new JSONArray(data.getJSONArray("forecast").toString());
            JSONObject txtForecast = forecast.getJSONObject("txt_forecast");
            JSONObject simpeForecast = forecast.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("simpleforecast"));

            // Loop through recipesJSON for desired info
            for (int i = 0; i < txtForecast.length(); i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "In for loop at index: " + i + " Object: " + forecast.getJSONObject(i));

                // This is where I was tring to obtain those fields
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "JSON array: " + weatherJSON);

        return weatherJSON;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reliable parser should have no trouble with that.  You just need to understand what it is.  Go to json.org and study the syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn and then things will make a lot more sense.  Note that trying to copy someone else's JSON processing code is usually a fool's errand, as the code must differ (quite radically) based on the structure of the JSON.

Comment: (You've got several things in your code that are just plain wrong -- essentially nonsense.)

Comment: (Unfortunately, your JSON is too long to post formatted, but you can view it formatted by pasting it in at http://json.parser.online.fr/ and the indentation will make it a lot easier to understand.)

Comment: This is nonsense: `forecast.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("simpleforecast"))`.

Comment: This is doing things the hard way, for no good reason: `new JSONArray(data.getJSONArray("forecast").toString())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON array starts with `[` and object starts with `{`. `forecast` is not an array in your JSON, so change this

```
JSONArray forecast = new JSONArray(data.getJSONArray("forecast").toString());
```

to

```
JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(data.getJSONObject("forecast").toString());
```

Additionally, `forecastday` is the array. So change the logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the try/catch that I got to work for me.

```
try {
    // Create JSON
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    // Create Array of weather objects
    JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(data.getJSONObject("forecast").toString());
    JSONObject txtForecast = new JSONObject(forecast.getJSONObject("txt_forecast").toString());
    JSONArray forecastDay = txtForecast.getJSONArray("forecastday");


    // TODO: Add more details to weather object with following info.
    //JSONObject simpleForecast = forecast.getJSONObject(forecast.getJSONObject("simpleforecast").toString());
    //JSONArray simpleForecastDay = simpleForecast.getJSONArray("forecastday");

    // Loop through recipesJSON for desired info
    for (int i = 0; i < forecastDay.length(); i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "In for loop at index: " + i + " Object: " + forecastDay.getJSONObject(i));

        // Obtain Fields
        String dayOfWeek = forecastDay.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
        String condition = forecastDay.getJSONObject(i).getString("icon");
        String forecastText = forecastDay.getJSONObject(i).getString("fcttext");
        String iconURL = forecastDay.getJSONObject(i).getString("icon_url");

        // Create instance of Weather
        Weather tempWeather = new Weather(dayOfWeek, condition, forecastText, iconURL);

        weatherJSON.add(tempWeather);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```